# gsub replacing substring containing trailing space not working

Tags: r, regex

I have strings and would like to replace a pattern like `(+ 1)` (i.e. `space`, `opening bracket`, `1-3 digits`, `closing bracket`.

for the string `str1 <- "6 (+1010)"`, `str2 <- "1 (+1)"`:

```
gsub("\\(\\+\\d{1,4}\\)", "", str1)
> "6 "
gsub("\\(\\+\\d{1,4}\\)", "", str2)
> "1 "
```

This works fine but still contains the trailing space; trying to address this, I have tried the following `regex`s without success:

- `gsub("\\(\\+\\d{1,4}\\) ", "", str1)`,
- `gsub("\\(\\+\\d{1,4}\\)\\s", "", str1)`,
- `gsub("\\(\\+\\d{1,4}\\)[[:space:]]", "", str1)`,

They all yield `"6 (+1)"`. For now I am going with another, separate `gsub()` call but I'm sure there must be another, better way.

I am expecting the output `6` (without trailing space).

Comment: `gsub("\\s*\\(\\+\\d{1,4}\\)", "", str1)`

Comment: However, you may really just `trimws()` your `(g)sub` result, it looks a more natural and idiomatic approach.

Comment: Awesome `trimws(gsub("\\(\\+\\d{1,4}\\)", "", "6 (+1)"))` works like a charm.